# How to import a typescript module into Svelte Component

Tags: typescript, svelte

I'm trying to import a self-written TypeScript module into a svelte component. But I'm receiving the error that the module was not exported from its file even though I have done that.
Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem ?

[image: ScreenShot of the Error]

**My Code:**

telegram_bot.ts

```
export class TelegramBotForSafetyMania {...}
```

Home.svelte

```
import * as telegramBot from './../telegram_bot';
let bot = TelegramBotForSafetyMania.startBot();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I should have imported the module without the `./` at the beginning. So the line

`import {TelegramBotForSafetyMania} from '../telegram_bot'`
solved this issue

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `startBot` is a static method on your class:

`telegram_bot.ts`:

```ts
export class TelegramBotForSafetyMania {...}
```

`Home.svelte`:

```ts
import * as telegramBot from './../telegram_bot';

const {TelegramBotForSafetyMania} = telegramBot;

let bot = TelegramBotForSafetyMania.startBot();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jsejcksn!
I found out that I should have imported the module without the `./` at the beginning.
So the line `import {TelegramBotForSafetyMania} from '../telegram_bot'` solved this issue.

Comment: However, now I'm facing another error while importing the module. I created a question to it. I will really appreciate it if you could help me with solving it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70876587/an-error-by-importing-self-written-typescript-modules-to-a-svelte-component