# An error by importing self-written TypeScript modules to a Svelte component

Tags: typescript, import, svelte, deno

I'm trying to import a self-written TypeScript-Module to a Svelte component. However, I'm receiving the following error when I try to import the Module with the following line

`import {TelegramBotForSafetyMania} from '../telegram_bot';`

we receive the following error:

[image]

So we tried to define the format of the imported file by writing .ts at the end of the file name:

`import {TelegramBotForSafetyMania} from '../telegram_bot.ts';`

but then we received the following error:

[image]

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you run `node scripts/setupTypescript.js`?

Comment: thank you for your answer @kenset. I actually had to set up the Svelte project to be able to handle TypeScript code. obviously, I used the wrong template when I created the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem which led to the error. I should simply have used the right Svelte template which was released by [svelte.dev](https://svelte.dev/) to be able to import TypeScript to the application.
Here is the link to the instruction that helped me to fix the template I'm using:
https://svelte.dev/blog/svelte-and-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding .ts after ...distancecalculator ?

see also import statement in usage example:
https://deno.land/x/distancecalculator@v1.1.4#usage-example-for-your-code